# scala string interpolation inject value dynamically

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I have two strings:

```scala
val s1: String = "aaa/$Y/$m/aaa_$Y$m$d" // this one has all three variables
val s2: String = "aaa/$Y/$m" // this one has only two variables

val myStrings: Seq[String] = Seq(s1, s2)

val myStringsUpdated: Seq[String] = myStrings.map(s => ???)
```

Can I inject `Y`, `m`, `d` values into `s1`, `s2` dynamically so I get `myStringsUpdated` sequence?

Comment: This does not answer the question. But if `m` / `d` / `Y` comes from a date object. You could use `.format` method with your string pattern

Comment: so if year = dtObject.year, month = dtObject.month and day = dtObject.day then would it be "aaa/$Y/$m/aaa_$Y$m$d".format(year, month, year, month, day) ?

Comment: Something like this should do the trick: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1qNWgX94TPiZiEvvcZU6jw

Everything between single quotes doesn't get interpreted by the date time formatter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tim already mentioned interpolation is done at compile-time, so you can't use it directly, but you could do a simple trick and wrap it into function:

```
//instead of plain interpolated string we've got function returning interpolated string
def s1(Y: String, m: String, d: String): String = s"aaa/$Y/$m/aaa_$Y$m$d" 
def s2(Y: String, m: String, d: String): String = s"aaa/$Y/$m" 

val myStrings: Seq[(String, String, String) => String] = Seq(s1, s2)

//you inject value by just applying function
val myStringsUpdated = myStrings.map(_.apply("1999", "11", "01"))

println(myStringsUpdated) //List(aaa/1999/11/aaa_19991101, aaa/1999/11)
```

Answer (score 3):

String interpolation is done at compile time so it has to know which variables are needed and where they will go. But it is just a shorthand for concatenating static `String` values and the results of `toString` calls, so it should be reasonably straightforward to build the string you want dynamically.

If you provide more details of the conditions/transformations then there are probably some clean solutions e.g. using `Option`.